# "data is not iterable" when reverse or sort the data using RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use `reverse` & `sort` on the `data` coming from the `RTK query`. Whenever, i revers, it's showing me the error.

> 'data is not iterable'

Here's my code.

```js
const {data, error, isLoading} = useGetTransactionsQuery()
const [modalState, setModalState] = useState<boolean>(false)

console.log(data.reverse())
```

Here is my whole code:- [**GitHub**](https://github.com/JoyShaheb/react-ts-budget-app/blob/main/src/components/Transaction/index.t.x).

And also, I tried this. And it didn't work at all.

```js
data.reverse()   
[...data].reverse()
Array.from(data).reverse();
```

In the case of `Array.from(data).reverse();`. This error showing.

> TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at Function.from ()

Comment: I guess, you are trying to use the reverse method on the data `object`, The reverse method is intended to be used on arrays, and it reverses the order of the elements in the array. @JoyShaheb

Comment: Try this `Array.from(data).reverse();` first convert it to an array using the `Array.from` function.

Comment: no, my data is an array of objects and it looks like this 
[
    {
      "id": "DTy1-rBBdB",
      "reason": "make payment",
      "label": "sdcsdc",
      "date": "09:10 pm 23/12/22",
      "amount": -111,
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": "lu6pUZdkJv",
      "reason": "make payment",
      "label": "dfvdfv",
      "amount": -2342343,
      "date": "06:05 PM 12/25/22",
      "color": "red"
    }
  ],

Comment: @DSDmark your solution gives this error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)

Comment: Did you using `GraphQL`? @JoyShaheb.

Comment: @DSDmark, no i am using REST API using RTK Query. I've attached a github link, please check it

Comment: Try this `if (!isLoading && error === null) {
  const reversedData = Array.from(data).reverse();
  // Use reversedData to render the transactions
}`

Comment: @DSDmark your latest solution helped, thank you

Comment: Did it solve the question? Did you get the answer?. In that case, let me make the proper answer.